# help with static variables in java

Tags: java, static, constructor, new-operator

I have a class,

```
class MyClass {
    private int val;
    public static final MyClass myObject = new MyClass(1);
    MyClass(int a){
        val = a;
    }
    public int getVal(){
        return val;
    }
    public MyClass func1(){
        MyClass temp = myObject;
        temp.val = 2;
        return temp;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        MyClass x = new MyClass(4);
        System.out.println(myObject.getVal());
        x.func1();
        System.out.println(myObject.getVal());
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
 1
 2
```

I was expecting it to print:

```
 1 
 1
```

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. I was expecting that `myObject` being a `final static` value cannot be changed, and when I do `MyClass temp = myObject`, I create a new object called `temp` of type `MyClass` and assign the value of `myObject` to this newly created object. Please correct me if I am wrong. It seems that the there is no new object created and `temp` simply points to the original `myObject`

EDIT: Thanks for the answers! I now understand that the `=` operator never makes a copy of the object, it just copies the reference. What I need is to make a copy of `myObject` and store it in `temp`. What would be the best way to achieve this?

EDIT2: Another strange behavoir or a feature of Java?

I modified the code slightly

```
class MyClass {
    private Integer val;
    public static final MyClass myObject = new MyClass(1);
    MyClass(int a){
        val = a;
    }
    public int getVal(){
        return val;
    }
    public MyClass func1(){
        MyClass temp = new MyClass(33);
        temp.val = myObject.val;
        temp.val = 2;
        return temp;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        MyClass x = new MyClass(4);
        System.out.println(myObject.getVal());
        MyClass y = x.func1();
        System.out.println(x.getVal());
        System.out.println(y.getVal());
        System.out.println(myObject.getVal());
    }
}
```

output is

```
 1
 4
 2
 1
```

Therefore, when I create `temp` using `new MyClass(33)` and then set `temp.val = 2`, it actually makes a copy of val. In other words, `temp.val` does not point to `myObject.val`. Why is this so?

Comment: I think you are trying to implement  Singleton Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Java
BTW, your question is already answeres in multiple answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MyClass temp = myObject;
```

That's not creating a new instance, it's just assigning the reference so that temp points to the same instance as myObject.

So your statement:

> I create a new object called temp  of
>   type MyClass

is incorrect, as you aren't creating a new object here, just assigning an object reference.

**EDIT**
If your goal is to make a copy of myObject and return it from `func1()`, then you could do this (by copy I assume you mean copying the `val` value as well, if you want to use a different value for `val` then you can adjust this code accordingly):

```
public MyClass func1(){
    MyClass temp = new MyClass(myObject.getVal());
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The field is `final`, which means that you cannot reassign the field.  Your `myObject` var, however, is not immutable. When you call `func1()` on your `myObject`,  you are changing `myObject.val` to 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are obtaining a reference to an instance of the MyClass object and modifying one of its members.  That reference is not immutable; only the field named myObj is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have kinda answered your own question. You are correct in saying that there isn't really a new object created by the line  `MyClass temp = myObject;` temp is only an object reference to your static instance of myClass.

You can check this by modifying the code as so.

```
public MyClass func1(){
    MyClass temp = myObject;
    System.out.println(myObject == temp);//print true
    temp.val = 2;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `=` operator assigns references, not objects like in C++.

A final field can only be assigned once. That does not mean that objects reachable through a final field can not be modified.

Put differently: Unlike C++'s `const`, `final` only protects the reference, not the object.

Comment: Kind of depends where you put the `const` in C++ (or C).

Answer (score 1):

After reading the posted answers:

If you want the temp reference variable to hold a ref. to an immutable object you can make your class immutable.

You can find more information on how to do that here:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29

or

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Answer (score 0):

Definition of the modifier final states that the object reference cannot be changed.
In the first code snippet

```
public static final MyClass myObject = new MyClass(1);
```

myObject is a final reference which is pointing to a object with val =1.
However this does not imply that the contents of the object cannot be changed.
the function func1() gets a reference on the object with value 1 and changes its val to 2.
thereby it is perfectly legal.

For the second snippet

```
public MyClass func1(){
    MyClass temp = new MyClass(33);
    temp.val = myObject.val;
    temp.val = 2;
    return temp;
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    MyClass x = new MyClass(4);              //line A
    System.out.println(myObject.getVal());  //returns 1
    MyClass y = x.func1();                  //line B
    System.out.println(x.getVal());         //line C
    System.out.println(y.getVal());         //line D
    System.out.println(myObject.getVal());
}
```

At line A obj with val 4 is created.
At line B func1 is called which in summary creates a new object with val=33 which is then changed to val=1 and then val=2.
At line C we get output 4 from the obj created at line A.
At line D we get output 2 from the changes we made in using line B.
At line E we get output 1 from the static final object which is not changed.